# iOS Facebook request more permissions forces me to login again

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, permissions, publish-actions

I'm trying to create a share via Facebook feature in my app.

Following the tutorials on facebook developers' site, I setup my project and the login works fine.

I cannot however make the request more permissions work. I need to ask the user for publish_actions permissions in order to be able to post on his behalf from my app.

I have for example the following active session:

> 2014-06-02 10:44:56.729 facebook[68183:60b] activeSession: ,
>   expirationDate: 2014-07-28 14:50:04 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-05-30
>   11:03:01 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000,
>   permissions:(
>       installed,
>       "public_profile" )>

and my code to try to share is:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
          if (!error){
            NSDictionary *permissions= [(NSArray *)[result data] objectAtIndex:0];
            if (![permissions objectForKey:@"publish_actions"]){
              // Permission hasn't been granted, so ask for publish_actions
              [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                                                            defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound){
                       // Permission not granted, tell the user we will not share to Facebook
                       NSLog(@"Permission not granted, we will not share to Facebook.");
                 } else {
                      // Permission granted, publish the OG story
                      [self requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.in.gr",@"url",@"messageTitle",@"Titleos",@"description",@"description", nil] andHttpMethod:@"POST"];
                                                                                  }

                                                                              } else {
                                                                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                                                  NSLog(@"Encountered an error requesting permissions: %@", error.description);
                                                                              }
                                                                          }];

                                  } else {
                                      // Permissions present, publish the OG story

                                      [self requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.in.gr",@"url",@"messageTitle",@"Titleos",@"description",@"description", nil] andHttpMethod:@"POST"];
                 }

            } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            NSLog(@"Encountered an error checking permissions: %@", error.description);
         }
}];
```

Although I have already logged in, when I try to request the additional permissions, it asks me again to login instead just asking me to approve the additional permissions. On top of this, even if I login again, it does not grant me after all the publish_actions permissions.

How can I request successfully the necessary for publish permissions?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that using the latest Facebook sdk (3.1+ I think), publish actions work only for reviewed and submitted apps.

If you wanna test it, you have to make a test version of your app from the facebook dashboard.

They made it a bit annoying now. Make sure you have setup everything correct on your facebook app dashboard, otherwise you will get errors when trying to share stuff via your app.